# How to resize bottom fixed div when top div is collapsed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have two divs, one on top, the other on the bottom. I need to have the bottom div fixed, and to resize and occupy the space above when the div on top is collapsed. Links to the scenarios below. Is this possible to accomplish using only CSS? This is for an angularJS application.

**UPDATE**: Support for older versions of browsers, specifically IE, must also be considered.

[Div1 expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdOmN.png)

[Div1 collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKQW.png)

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using **[flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**. See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").click(function() {
    $(this).css("max-height", "50px")
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #4472C4;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #ED7D31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

### Update

Since you noted in the comments you wanna support older browsers, the same as above can be achieved using the old fasion `table` layout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").click(function() {
    $(this).css("height", "50px")
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #4472C4;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #ED7D31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box" id="div1">
        <strong>div1</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box" id="div2">
        <strong>div1</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If downvoting, explain why you are downvoting. Because in my opinion, this matches OP's desired result.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I wouldn't be able to use flex as I'm also targeting older versions of IE.

Comment: Alright, you should put that into your question though. As this was not clear in the current version of your question. I will update the awnser though.

Comment: Updated the question! I wouldn't want to use jQuery selectors, but I'm still accepting the answer as the HTML/CSS part is clear. Just FYI, I'd be using a combo of ng-click and ng-style to set the height of div1. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.content {
  display: table-row;
  /* height is dynamic, and will expand... */
  height: 100%;
  /* ...as content is added (won't scroll) */
  background: yellow;
}
.footer {
  display: table-row;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
    <p>Footer of variable height</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this it works fine for me

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="top-div">
        topd div
     </div>
     <div class="bottom-div">
        bottom div
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}
.container {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

.top-div {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom-div {
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

use jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var containerH = $(".container").height();
  var topdivH = $(".top-div").height();
  $(".bottom-div").height(containerH - topdivH);
});
```

check out [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timoleon/w08mcnnv/4/)

Comment: in my solution when the top div changes his height then the bottom div follows the change...